# why does sum() query returns result with more decimal points?

Tags: mysql, floating-point, sum, decimal

[image]

The above image shows one of the columns named 'igstAmt' in my database table.
when i use the query `"SELECT sum(igstAmt) as igstAmt FROM salesinvoice`, it returns the value `21616.7500129491` with many decimal points, but the correct answer is `21616.75`. I know I can round up the result while displaying, I want to know why is this happening like this? The maximum number of decimal points in the entries in that column is two, so the result also should have 2 decimal points, right? The datatype of the column is `float`.

Comment: if your data type is decimal(16,2) then it would return like your expectation, as it is float that's why it is like this

Comment: i wonder, how the query is finding the values after 2 decimal points?

Comment: its because of the data type

Comment: Google "floating point precision". Changing to a `decimal` data type will solve the problem,  or you can just round.

Comment: Use `DECIMAL(m,n)` for storing "money"; use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for "scientific" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `float` data type does not represent numbers with decimal digits. It represents numbers with binary, so the binary digits in the numbers represent powers of two such as 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, ½, ¼, ⅛, and so on.

The numbers shown as “272.7”, “0.55”, and so on are not accurate representations of the stored values. For example, the number shown as “272.7” may actually be 272.70001220703125.

The rules used to format numbers for output may hide these differences from you by using fewer than all the digits needed to show the exact value.

When you add these numbers, the differences between the actual numbers and the nearby decimal representations may grow or shrink, depending on chance variations between the differences. The sum you are seeing is a natural result of these additions.

Comment: More precisely, I can recreate the result by storing the values in single-precision (binary32), but computing the sum in double-precision (binary64).

Comment: @SimonByrne - That is since `FLOAT` holds only 24 bits of precision (about 7 significant decimal digits) and `DOUBLE` works with 53 bits (about 16 digits).  Note how the long numbers went sour after about 7 'good' digits.