# COALESCE + SUM in MYSQL incorrectly calculating

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I am using COALESCE and SUM to get the total value of payments for each invoice.  Below is relative data.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(p.payment_amount),0) as amount_paid 
FROM Payments as p 
WHERE p.invoice = '13923';
```

Below is database information relative to the issue

```
invoice   type    payment_amount
13923    Credit    51.19
13923    Check     592.93
```

The problem is, the total due on the invoice is 644.12.  When I manually add the two payment amounts together, it equals 644.12 which is exact payment.  But when I run the query and look at the results, it is showing that the `payment_amount = 644.1199999999999`

Anyone understand how it is coming up with this or see any issues with my code or a better way of doing this?

***NOTE: The reason I'm using COALESCE is because sometimes there are payments and sometimes there are not.  So I need the value to either be the total amount paid OR 0 if no records found in payments.  This code is combined within a longer query but tried posting only relative data.***

Comment: What is the datatype of column `payment_amount`?

Comment: I bet it's not decimal.. Odds on it's REAL

Comment: @GMB - varchar128  ... but even with that, why wouldnt it add correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using the [ROUND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function would give you the result you're looking for

```
ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(p.payment_amount),0),2)
```

---

After discussing this further in the comments this would be my proposed solution

Update the `payment_amount` column to DECIMAL(15,2) datatype

```
CREATE TABLE `Payments` (
  `payment_amount` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `Payments` (`payment_amount`) VALUES ('51.19');

INSERT INTO `Payments` (`payment_amount`) VALUES ('592.93');

SELECT SUM(payment_amount) FROM Payments;
```

Outputs 644.12

Comment: I could understand this if I was adding 23.29384 + 294.293495, but trying to understand why adding 592.93 + 51.19 could end up being 644.1199999999999 .... its a pretty straight forward addition statement that SHOULDNT really need to be rounded

Comment: Maybe this SO answer might give you a better understanding of the behavior 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51925191/13520068

Comment: I can understand that for system generated numbers, but these numbers I am showing above are what we are entering for the data.  They are manual entered payment amounts from checks.  So in a text field, we entered 51.19 and we entered 592.93.  Any other explanation on how these could have been represented differently?

Comment: is there a better data type for the 'payment_amount' mysql column that would fix this without having to add round()?  It is always going to be dollar amounts (  293,  297.35, 0.10,  etc. )

Comment: Maybe have a look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` for convert sim to decimal and should do `COALESCE` before `SUM`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
      CAST(COALESCE(p.payment_amount, 0) AS DECIMAL(12,2))
    ) as amount_paid 
FROM Payments as p 
WHERE p.invoice = '13923';
```

Comment: that is neat.  I ended up changing my database column to DECIMAL so I avoided having to do this.  But interesting method of conversion.